# Always call a function in cakePhp

Tags: cakephp

I would like to know how I can use a function in cakePHP that will always be call when I load a page?

More precisions with this example:

I have my main page: index.ctp
I have another page: profil.ctp

What I want is, when I try to access profil.ctp, if I'm not logged, it will automatically redirect me to the index.ctp page.

What I already done:

UsersController:

```
function index() {
    if (!empty($this->data))
        $this->Session->write(array('User' => array('connected' => true)));
}
```

ProfilsController:

```
function index() {
  if (!$this->Session->read('connected'))
    $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to add this code to each pages, and each functions of all my controllers.

Any ideas ?

Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the code in your `AppController.php`s beforeFilter()

If you use the `beforeFilter` in other controllers make sure to call `parent` before the other code.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    // your other code
}
```

In each controller, the `beforeFilter()` is called, which then triggers the AppController (parent) `beforeFilter()`.

Comment: It's seems working, but I have another problem now, I have a loop with the redirection. I put in my ProfileController 

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
}
but not in my UsersController because this page will set the "connected" flag, and also put in my appController:
    public function beforeFilter() {
        if (!$this->Session->read('User.connected'))
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
    }

Any ideas how I can fix it ?

Comment: @4m0ni4c - It's very difficult to read in a comment, and is mostly unrelated to the current question.  Post your new code/attempt in a new question, and I'd be glad to look into it further.

Comment: adding `beforeFilter()` functions that contains only `parent::beforeFilter();` in controllers is absolutely useless

Comment: @nIcO - I disagree (and apparently so does the CakePHP community, since it's specifically suggested [in the CakePHP book here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller)) - it's very normal, and has many benefits as opposed to making a specific function call in many controllers.  Function names can change, required functionality can change, function options can change...etc etc etc - much better to have all your code in one place than in many many places.

Comment: I think you didn't get what I meant. I just meant that in oo programming, overriding a method only to call the parent overridden method is useless because this only results in wrapping the parent method, thus adding one level to the call stack without adding anything else. But the remark you pointed out in the cookbook does exist indeed and seems very strange to me. It has to be clarified.

Comment: The book does not state that you should put that in all controllers. The problem is that it is not clear that you should put it in all controllers when defining the callback. 'within child controller callbacks', so if you don't have the callback there is nothing to put it in. Basic OOP principals. Telling users they should define this empty callback with a parent::method() call is akin to saying you should do echo ($var); not just echo $var;. The only thing both examples achieve is making some poor n00b write more code for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Put the code in your `AppController` `beforeFilter()`

AppController:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
  //call your code here
}
```

In your controllers, override the `beforeFilter()` function only if you need to run specific code that must be executed each time an action in the specific controller is called.

Some examples:

UsersController:

```
UsersController extends AppController
{
  public function beforeFilter()
  {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    //add some code here that must be run before each UsersController's action
  }

  ...

}
```

LogsController:

If you don't need to call any specific code before the LogsController's actions are used, don't add any `beforeFilter()` function. The AppController `beforeFilter()` will be used thanks to object inheritance.

```
LogsController extends AppController
{
  //no need for a beforeFilter() here ! 
  //AppController's beforeFilter() will be used automatically

  ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, I just understood why it was not working as I wanted. I just had to check in the AppController, if the current controller was not User. Thx for all your answers